# The function time is not being recognised in my python script

Tags: time, python-datetime, strftime

The time tags are not being identified and the "time" function is not being recognised or called. The requirement is to output the current date and time

```
import time
now= time.strftime(%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S)
print("It is", now)
```

This is the code I tired, but unfortunately, I am getting an error.

```
now= time.strftime(%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Above is the error I am getting

Comment: You probably want to enclose your format-string into double-quotes `"` Ie `strftime("%b ... ")` 
 See also the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime